# Is there a way to add the ISBLANK function so that if no data is entered into in "b1" nothing will display in excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, count

Current formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A1:A10,b1),"SMALL","LARGE")
```

Formula I am trying:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A1:A10,b1),"SMALL","LARGE",ISBLANK(""))
```

If `b1` is blank, I would like the cell with this formula to also display as blank.

Answer (score 1):

Nest the IF:

```
=IF(B1="","",IF(COUNTIFS(A1:A10,b1),"SMALL","LARGE"))
```

Comment: You're the best!!